# Not able to show minimal height for a bar in highcharts

Tags: angular, d3.js, charts, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am trying to add minimum height to the bar / column / stacked-column chart when there is huge difference in the values of the item and I am not able to see any plot for minimum value in the highcharts.

Series Can we huge as below:
[10000012123, 78, 57896877, 789098674]

Here my second value is not visible in chart and I want to add some minimum height to the column.

Can someone help me out, to figure out if this feature is available with highcharts or I will need to raise a request with highcharts team?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think `minPointLength` can work for your case

```js
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            minPointLength: 3
        }
    },
```

**[API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.minPointLength)**

**[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-minpointlength/)**

Comment: It is not working in case of stacked chart, if both of my values are low.  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/mayurirathod/34h2ypwq/)